# unable to access the manually created assets folder with Java class using Java Library

Tags: java, android, fonts, assets

[image]

Getting below error as-

java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found arial.ttf

Comment: you have created an asset folder wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Try to create a assest folder like this then put your font file in it, then it will work.

[image]

Your asset file structure should show like this [Icon under the file name], yours seems like normal folder.

Comment: Yes, It works if i follow the above process for App, but  i am creating assets folder for Java Library not for "App".  Android Studio not provides above process to create the asset folder for Java library.